# custom className semantic ui react

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, classname, semantic-ui-react

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
<Divider className="homepage-divider" />
```

But no matter if I add a class name this is all that shows up:

```
<div class="ui divider"></div>
```

How do I make my own className.  I would like to use the divider multiple times with different widths.  I know how to customize it with the override files already but that would set my regular divider to a set width.

Comment: [Looking at the source](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/50b324165fd2908d0b4aab66d3b02e3a61886a9e/src/elements/Divider/Divider.js#L18), you should be able to give a custom `className`. Could you show more of your code?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue of using the  `className` . The class was getting applied when I viewed the source but the  `margin`  for which the class was added wasn't applied.

Later, I figured that the default classes such as  `ui, divider`  of semantic-ui have their own  `margin`  added.

**Solution:**

Add  `!important`  for the css property which is getting overwritten by sematic-ui css classes.

> e.g: *divider.jsx*

```
import React from 'react';
import { Divider } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import './styles.css';
const CustomDivider = () => <Divider className='custom-margin-class'/>;
export default CustomDivider;
```

> *styles.css*

```
.custom-margin-class {
    margin: 8px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as Tholle mentioned, it should work.
see working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/2p398kyykr

Answer (score 0):

That's very odd, when i strip out everything in the file and try something similar to your codesandbox it works.  I will play around with my code and post what the issue is once I figure it out